# Object reference not set Error, On Return to Plugins/PaymentPayPalStandard/PDTHandler after payment from paypal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal-sandbox, checkout, nopcommerce

1. I setup PDT Token in my NopCommerece site for Paypall payment.
2. I setup a Return Url of http://www.example.com/Plugins/PaymentPayPalStandard/PDTHandler at Paypal configuration.

I check out successfuly, But when its time to come back to this page. It Gives me the following Exception.

---

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**Source Error:**

The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

or:

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

```
   <compilation debug="true"/>
```

Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.

Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.

**Stack Trace:**

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Nop.Plugin.Payments.PayPalStandard.PayPalStandardPaymentProcessor.GetPDTDetails(String tx, Dictionary`2& values, String& response) +178
   Nop.Plugin.Payments.PayPalStandard.Controllers.PaymentPayPalStandardController.PDTHandler(FormCollection form) +262
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +138
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +228
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3f() +71
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41() +386
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41() +386
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41() +386
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41() +386
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41() +386
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c() +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +186
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +524
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +167

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but, Once i used to  PaypalStandard plugin in NopCom.

I found few things,
1. Parameter's set to Paypal are differ than what assumed in NopCom plugin.
2. I have received response without any data always when i tried.

So you need to either change the response handler code or try to use paypal api first to understand the structure.